# How do I code a command block so that it checks for if a player is wearing a specific Helmet called "☀ Disco Helm ☀"?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I made this Helmet via command blocks and I want to program a command block so that it always checks for if the player is wearing this Helmet, and if the player is wearing it, it replaces a the block on the coordinates 1 4 4 with a redstone block. I tried using the /execute command - my attempt was:

`/execute as @p[nbt={Inventory:[{Slot:102b,tag:{Name:"{\"☀ Disco Helm ☀\"}"}}]}] run setblock 1 4 4 minecraft:redstone_block replace`

[image: Disco Helm is the name of the Helmet]

This however didn't work and I'm thinking it's because of the fact that the name of the Helmet has a lot of different colors?

I'm an amateur to command blocks, so I would really appreciate if someone could fix my code, especially this part:

`[nbt={Inventory:[{Slot:102b,tag:{Name:"{\"☀ Disco Helm ☀\"}"}}]}]`

Comment: Hey there! Welcome to Arquade!

Comment: Run the command `data get entity @s Inventory[{Slot:103b}].tag` while the helmet is on your head.  The slot for the helmet is `103b` and not `102b`.  I’m pretty sure you need to put the nbt `Name` in another tag named `display`.  Once you’ve run the command, edit your answer to include the results of the data command.

Answer (score 1):

here is the working command. For an explaination, see below.

```
/execute as @s[nbt={Inventory:[{Slot:103b,id:"minecraft:leather_helmet",tag:{display:{Name:"{\"name\":\"☀ \",\"color\":\"gold\","italic":"false"},\"name\":\"D\",\"color\":\"dark_red\"},{\"name\":\"i\",\"color\":\"red\"},{\"name\":\"s\",\"color\":\"gold\"},{\"name\":\"c\",\"color\":\"yellow\"},{\"name\":\"o \",\"color\":\"green\"},{\"name\":\"H\",\"color\":\"aqua\"},{\"name\":\"e\",\"color\":\"blue\"},{\"name\":\"l\",\"color\":\"light_purple\"},{\"name\":\"m\",\"color\":\"purple\"},{\"name\":\" ☀\",\"color\":\"yellow\"}"}}}]}] run setblock 1 4 4 minecraft:redstone_block replace`
```

You need to specify the color for each change in color. That was the only error in your command. I have to admit, it is painstaking. If the above command doesn't work, please tell me what color you set the spaces to in the comments. (Yes, spaces have a color)

You're welcome,
ShadeOfLight

Answer (score 0):

I see a few problems, and I have one suggestion.

In order to spot the problems, let's expand your NBT into a layered structure:

```
0: nbt={
1:     Inventory:[
2:         {
3:             Slot:102b,
4:             tag:{
5:                 Name:"{\"☀ Disco Helm ☀\"}"
6:             }
7:         }
8:     ]
9: }
```

The problems:

1. The item structure is different—the Name tag goes inside another tag named `display`.
   Wrong way:

   ```
   tag:{
       Name:'...'
   }
   ```

   Right way:

   ```
   tag:{
       display:{
           Name:'...'
       }
   }
   ```
2. The raw text in the `Name` tag is malformed. When checking if the name matches, the system does a *plain text check on the raw JSON source*, and does not look at the final name after rendering. So hold the item in your main hand, and run the following command in your chat:

   ```
   /data get entity @s SelectedItem.tag.display.Name
   ```

   Look for the text in GREEN, that represents the raw JSON source of the name. In the original command, place the GREEN text into the Name tag. Make sure you escape double quotes where necessary.